# Using the Existence and Uniqueness theorem for differential equations did not work

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to solve
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{(x-2)(x-1)y' - (4x-3)y=(x-2)^{2}}}$$

The solution provided me an answer using the variation of parameters method, and not using the formula in the Existence and Uniqueness Theorem. However, both my answer and the solution's answer are different. Can anyone tell me what I did wrong.

[#1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wJsFk.png)

As you can see,
$$\displaystyle{\displaylines{y_{1} = (x-2)^5/(x-1)}}$$
is correct in both the solution and my working. It's just when I apply y1 to the formula, I end up with a different answer.

This is my answer:
[#2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TuVvW.png)

The theorem I am using
[The Theorem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cw4ob.png)

If anybody can help, that would be great.

[The book's solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pkUSL.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is necessary to write the DE in its standard form to correctly identify $y_1$ and $f(x)$ (it should be of the form: $y'+P(x)y=f(x)$)

Letting $$P(x):=\frac{-4x+3}{(x-2)(x-1)},\quad \color{red}{f(x):=\frac{x-2}{x-1}}$$
The DE has the standard form $y'+P(x)y=f(x)$ which is linear DE, then one can use the theorem (in fact it is derived from parameter variation).

Using the theorem with $y_1=\frac{(x-2)^5}{(x-1)}$ one has
\begin{align*}
y=&y_1\left(C+\int f(x)/y_1\right)\\
&=\frac{(x-2)^5}{(x-1)}\left(C+\int \frac{(x-1)}{(x-2)^5}\times \frac{(x-2)}{(x-1)}dx\right)\\
&=\color{red}{\frac{(x-2)^5}{(x-1)}\left(C+\int \frac{1}{(x-2)^4}dx \right)}\\
&=\frac{(x-2)^5}{(x-1)}\left(C+\frac{-1/3}{(x-2)^3}\right)\\
&=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{3}}\frac{(x-2)^\color{red}{2}}{(x-1)}+C\frac{(x-2)^5}{(x-1)}.
\end{align*}

Notice that if $C=0$ then $y_p=-\frac{1}{3}\frac{(x-2)^2}{(x-1)}$ given $(x-2)(x-1)y'-(4x-3)y\equiv (x-2)^2$. However if $y_p=\color{red}{-\frac{1}{2}}\frac{(x-2)^\color{red}{3}}{(x-1)}$ give $(x-2)(x-1)y'-(4x-3)y\equiv (x-2)^\color{red}{3}$.